# Ruby on Rails. Error with relation in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models in ruby. The school and the course.

The `course` model have:

```
belongs_to :school
```

The `school` model have:

```
has_many :courses
```

The routes are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :projects
resources :schools
resources :documents
resources :courses
resources :subjects
resources :people
resources :persontypes
end
```

the method create for courses is :

```
def create
 @course = Course.new(course_params)

 if @course.save
    redirect_to courses_path
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end
```

My schema is:

```
create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.text     "name"
  t.integer  "code"
  t.text     "initials"
  t.integer  "school_id"
 end


create_table "schools", force: :cascade do |t|
t.text     "description"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.text     "name"
t.integer  "code"
t.text     "initials"
end
```

I create a school. But when I try to create a course it gives me a error: It´s say that I need a school.

I already have both models related but how can I put in the create view of the courses a list to choose to which school belongs that course?

EDITED:

My controler for delete method is

```
def destroy
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    @course.destroy

    redirect_to courses_path
end
```

When I delete a course, instead of the course being deleted, I'm redirected to the view edit.

This is the code for the delete link:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Remover', course_path(course), 
method: :delete, 
data: { confirm: 'Tem a certeza que deseja eliminar este Curso?' } %></td>
```

Is a route problem?

Comment: Can you please add the method `create` on your `courses_controller`?

Comment: Please, provide part of the code, where you receive this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to nest course inside school routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :schools do
    resources :courses 
  end
end
```

In that case your url will look like `/schools/1/courses/new`.

Than you'll need to update your controller:

```
def create
  @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
  @course = @school.courses.new(course_params)
  #...
end
```

In the case, if you need to select school from the dropdown just add select form input.

Here is a great doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select

Update course creation form (naive implementation):

```
#...
<%= f.select :school_id, School.all.collect { |s| [s.name, s.id] }, include_blank: true %>
#...
```

And you'll definately need to whitelist `school_id` param in your controller.

Comment: But how can i ,for example, put a list in new.html.erb for when you i create a course, can select the desired school

Comment: I have put like this:
-------------------------------------
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :projects
  #resources :schools
  resources :documents
  #resources :courses
  resources :subjects
  resources :people
  resources :persontypes

  resources :schools do
    resources :courses 
  end
-------------------------------------

but it gives me an error: No route matches [GET] "/courses"

Comment: Your routes will look like: `/schools/:school_id/courses`

Comment: If you'll select school from the select input field, than there is no need to nest routes/change controllers create action. Just update form and whitelist `school_id` param.

Comment: Now i can create a course but When I want to delete the course it goes to the edit page. Does this have to do with the routes?

Comment: What do you mean by "it goes"? Have you checked delete link or controller code?

Comment: `link_to 'Remover', course, ...` should work. Or, maybe, use `button_to` helper.

Comment: `button_to` generates form with submit button and it is "safest way" to create "non-GET links". (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)